# VS2010 project folder Unable to change Read Only attribute

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have a VS2010 solution file connected to TFS. My Solution contains 3 projects for Data, Business and the Web front end.

I need to copy this solution file and related folders to a network location from where it will be moved to a different source code system.

I tried copying my solution file and related files and it has a read only attribute associated to it. I removed the read only attribute and right click and properties the read only attributes still exists.

I think it is some form of association between the solution file and TFS. Is there a solution remove the read only attribute?

Comment: Is it a folder or a file that has the read-only attribute?  Changing it on a file within the folder wouldn't necessarily un-set the attribute on the folder.

Comment: @ Ann L. - Thanks! It is the entire folder. I did on the parent folder and selected the Apply changes to folder, subfolders and files. Then I right click on the parent folder and the read only check box is checked.

Comment: The "read only" attribute you are looking at is misleading... _it has no meaning for folders._ Look at the security tab for the ntfs permissions instead to see actual read/write permissions... but I suspect your real issue lies elsewhere.